# How to do caption hover effect on a background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm currently working on a background for a website in which I want to add a hover effect with text on top. Though I came across a problem where I have my background image on a css style sheet and having some difficulties implementing the hover.

I have came across some good resources on hover effects such as [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/) and [this one](http://ryun.github.io/HCaptions/). The one on github is pretty nifty, but since I'm not very knowledgeable with j query, I will stick with the basic one.

Here is my background code on css, the question is how would I implement the hover from here?

```
body {
min-width: 800px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-left: 50px solid #000000;
background: #FF7F66 url('images/landscape1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
color: #666666;
font: 10px Verdana;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `body:hover{/*styles*/}` ?

Comment: You could so something similar with http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ easily.

Comment: @Oriol No I haven't, actually I'm not even sure how to begin it. Is it the same way as hovering with text?

Comment: @Christian Looks at little intimidating, but I will see what I could do.

Comment: You could achieve the effect pretty easily using just transit.js, jquery and few lines of css. Just target the element, and it's done. `$(".div-class").translate({x:10, y:10});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a css psuedo selector:

```
.wrapper:hover 
{
    /* whatever styles you want */
}
```

As far as I know, you can't put a pseudo selector on the body. You should just use a wrapper similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/wyehq/

Comment: Of course it's possible to use a pseudo selector on the body. Why not?

Comment: I wasn't able to get the :hover psuedo class to work with the body in Chrome, maybe it just isn't supported?

Comment: On Firefox, both pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements work. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CLavs/)